# Hyperledger Composer Participant creation validation

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

How can I validate the existence of  a a resource when a participant is created
for example:

```
participant Trader identified by traderId {
  o String traderId
  o String traderFirstName
  o String traderLastName
  --> Car owner
}
```

and there is an asset:

```
participant Car identified by carId {
  o String carId
  o string vin
}
```

When I create a new participant I've to assign a Car to him.  When I do that using the CLI or a Restful API or composer-playground there's no validation that this `Car` exists or not.  How can I make sure that it exists so that when I create a participant `Trader` it should be mapped to an existing instance of the asset `Car` not to an asset that doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the "system transactions" AddParticipant and AddAsset from Playground and the REST server.

If you want to do the checking, you will need to write your own Transaction and execute a `get` on the Car registry (though maybe you should really define the Car as an Asset not a Participant) to check the presence of the owner, and then a `put` on the Trader registry.

I would suggest looking at the Transactions in the Samples in Playground for examples of writing Transaction scripts.  Please also see this [reference document](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/js_scripts.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was wondering how to disable or override the main CRUD created by the framework in order to work with that in the Transactions only?